# Добавление новых значений в базу SQLite используя переменную

Tags: python, sqlite

Добрый день.
Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу добавлять значение в базу данных используя переменную.

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("base_122_Test.db")
cur = con.cursor()

p_name = "Иван" # переменная со значением имени

sql = """

INSERT INTO user (name, last_name, second_name, phone)

VALUES (p_name, "Иванов", "Иванович", "+7(998)254-60-77")

"""

con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()
input()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте метод [execute](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute):

```
sql = """
INSERT INTO user (name, last_name, second_name, phone)
VALUES (?, "Иванов", "Иванович", "+7(998)254-60-77")
"""

cur.execute(sql, (p_name,))
```

Альтернативный вариант передачи параметра:

```
sql = """
INSERT INTO user (name, last_name, second_name, phone)
VALUES (:p_name, "Иванов", "Иванович", "+7(998)254-60-77")
"""

cur.execute(sql, {'p_name': p_name})
```

Comment: еще можно `"INSERT INTO OT (File) VALUES(?)",o`

Comment: опция для ленивых: `cur.execute(sql, vars())`